# Update table where column starts with value 'st'%

Tags: mysql

Im trying to update column brand where productcode starts with ST

```
 `Update outerbarcodes set brand='A' where productcode = 'ST%';`
```

for some reason this code above isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Use `like` operator instead of `=`

```
 Update outerbarcodes set brand='A' where productcode like 'ST%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... Whats the difference? just curious

Comment: @Eduards, you are matching string that's why you need like where as = will check exact value for example name='xyz' it will return only xyz but if you use like 'x%' it will return all sho start with x

Comment: Ahh understood!